# Order main block after sidebar on xs size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How I can order xs size blocks?
I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        MAIN
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        SIDEBAR
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to get SIDEBAR block on top page when resizing page to xs size.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `col-*-push-*` and `col-*-pull-*`. `push` will move the container left and `pull` will move the container right.

So in your example:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-xs-12">
    SIDEBAR
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4 col-xs-12">
    MAIN
</div>
```

That should do the trick.
Also note that I excluded the `lg` and `md` classes. Bootstrap automatically uses the largest available class for larger screens. So if you don't specify `lg` and `md` but do specify `sm`, it will use the `sm` for medium and large.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r8MHK/)

Comment: Thank you for answer, you really helped me! And also thank you for mentioning about `ld` and `md` useless using. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-xs-12`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        MAIN
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        SIDEBAR
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't resolved my problem. Still SIDERBAR bar is under MAIN on xs size.